# Why is my Galaxy S notifying me about a new message when my inbox is empty?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, notifications

My Galaxy S keeps telling me I have a text message. I have erased my entire inbox but the notification won't go away. How do I make this notification stop?

Comment: What kind of message? An email? A text message? Better: what app are you seeing this in? Also, note that the [Motorola Droid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_Droid) (which you tagged this with) is **very** different from a Galaxy S.

Comment: a text message. and yes I have to edit that. can you fix it???

Comment: Tap the notification once... you'll not get that again..